# Cassandra Performance : Less rows with more columns vs more rows with less columns

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax-java-driver

We are evaluating if we can migrate from SQL SERVER to cassandra for OLAP. As per the internal storage structure we can have wide rows. We almost need to access data by the date. We often need to access data within date range as we have financial data. If we use date as Partition key to support filter by date,we end up having less row with huge number of columns. 
Will it hamper performance if we have millions of columns for a single row key in future as we process millions of transactions every day.

Do we need to have some changes in the access pattern to have more rows with less number of columns per row.

Need some performance insight to proceed in either direction

Answer (score 3):

Using wide rows is typically fine with Cassandra, there are however a few things to consider:

- Ensure that you don't reach the 2 billion column limit in any case
- The whole wide row is stored on the same node: it needs to fit on the disk. Also, if you have some dates that are accessed more frequently then other dates (e.g. today) then you can create hotspots on the node that stores the data for that day.
- Very wide rows can affect performance however: Aaron Morton from The Last Pickle has an interesting article about this: http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2011/07/04/Cassandra-Query-Plans.html
  It is somewhat old, but I believe that the concepts are still valid.

For a good table design decision one needs to know all typical filter conditions. If you have any other fields you typically filter for as an exact match, you could add them to the partition key as well.

Comment: thanks for your comment. reaching 2 billion column limit is very unlikely. Wide row not fitting on a particular disk might be the case. Does not cassandra handle such a case where row is not fitting on the disk. It should transfer data to another node as choosing the node to save the row is  internal storage engine's decision.

Comment: Data partitioning in Cassandra is driven by the partition key: with a simple and fast hashing algorithm Cassandra identifies the node which holds the data. In this respect the wide row is a unit, it is not split among nodes. Eventually try to introduce other fields into the partition key (e.g. the id of the financial product, the year or even the month if it makes sense).

Comment: If hashing algorithm identifies a node on which row can not fit or fit initially but as wide row grow eventually then does cassandra transfer the row to some other machine or not ?

Comment: Cassandra does not share rows among nodes, the whole row is placed on a single node (not talking about replication now). No transfer mechanism is implemented, as it would considerably decrease performance. You could check this article for more details on partitioning and replication: http://www.datastax.com/resources/tutorials/partitioning-and-replication